# I try to proxy all the paths but only does with the root one

Tags: docker, nginx, proxy, webserver

I try to proxy with nginx the port 80 to 3030 where I have my container running however only the root works, the rest of the URL I get not found, this is my config

```
server {
        server_name example.com;


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

                proxy_pass     https://localhost:3030;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        Host    $http_host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 
                proxy_redirect         http://localhost:3030 http://example.com;

        }

}
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 ;
}
```

I try to proxy all the paths of the project without having `not found` issue

Comment: Remove the `try_files` statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot! it was the issue

Answer (score 0):

As Richard Smith replied me I needed to remove the line `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` then everything works and I can proxy my docker.